# Hudson: archive log of server under test

Tags: hudson

How can I archive the logs of the server under test?

I have a glassfish hosting two domains: the hudson and the SUT (System Under Test) domains. I have hudson running functional tests on the SUT. It'd be very valuable to archive the logs of the SUT generated during testing.

I have tried to configure the "Archive the artifacts" text field to archive the log, providing an absolute path to the log (`/srv/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log`), but Hudson cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess using a script that copies the SUT logs into the hudson's working directory would be one option.